# how to auto restart modem by running script

Tags: javascript

```
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<title>TL-WR841N</title>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="wed, 26 Feb 1997 08:21:57 GMT">
<link href="/dynaform/css_main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="javascript" src="/dynaform/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--
if(window.parent == window){window.location.href="http://192.168.1.1";}
function Click(){ return false;}
document.oncontextmenu=Click;
//--></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//
function doSubmit()
{
    if(confirm(js_to_reboot="Are you sure to reboot this device?"))
    {
        location.href = "/userRpm/SysRebootRpm.htm";
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
//--></script>
</head>
<body onload="setTagStr(document,'ntw_sys_reboot');LoadHelp('SysRebootHelpRpm.htm'); resize(this);" onresize="resize(this);" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<center>
  <form action="SysRebootRpm.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get" onsubmit="return doSubmit();">
    <table id="autoWidth" style="width: 950px;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="h1" id="t_title">Reboot</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="blue"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="info" id="t_notice">Click this button to reboot this device.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="mbtn"><input name="Reboot" type="submit" class="buttonBig" value="Reboot" id="reboot"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="blue"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</center>


<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">


</body></html>
```

Above is from the modem page.
Is there is a way to extract the javascript to make reboot modem as easy as one-click.
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You could probably save that URL as a browser bookmark, but wouldn't the modem expect you to logon before you can navigate to it?

Comment: Can't I just hardcode the id password in the html?